# How can I explore Jenkins workspace?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, workspace

I want to scan file stored in my Jenkins project workspace.
for example, when I make a project named `my_project`, I will get report pattern from Jenkins like `**/report.xml`. and to find `report.xml` file, I will explore in my own plugin.
since when I print pwd on jenkins console, it prints where my plugin written, not jenkins workspace. so I need to know how to explore jenkins workspace in my plugin.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking where your jenkins workspace is, it is in the workspace folder where you can find all your projects. It should be relative to your plugin folder: `../workspace`. You can try to change directory using the relative path. Hope this helps.

Comment: your sentence 'your projects' means the project I made in Jenkins?

Comment: yup in the workspace folder (following the relative path), you will find your project `my_project` there

Comment: Jenkins client usually know the workspace through environment variable.